# How to execute javascript after DOM is loaded in cycle.js

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, reactive-programming, cyclejs

How can I execute javascript after the DOM is loaded in [cycle.js](https://cycle.js.org/)?  I can't put it in my `main()` because the DOM is not loaded at that point.  For context, I'm basically trying to initialize a fancy autocomplete which requires the target DOM element to exist, please feel free to give pointers if my approach is wrong.

I tried this:

```
sources.DOM.select(':root')
  .observable.take(1)
  .subscribe((element) => initAutoCompl())
```

...but `select` was returning `null`, I also tried selecting against other elements as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way (using [CycleJS](https://cycle.js.org/) with [xstream](https://github.com/staltz/xstream/blob/master/README.md)) to execute JS code once after the DOM is ready is to run a (otherwise) non-operative observable. To do that `select` `':root'` then assign a non-existent event, and initiate the stream with `startWith`. Once the stream is initiated run a `map` that executes your setup function. To subscribe to the observable send it to a non-operative driver:

```
function main (sources) {

  // Initiate observable, run setup function
  const noop$ = sources.DOM.select(':root').events('noop')
    .startWith(1).map(noop => runSetup())

...

  return {
    DOM: vdom$,
    noop: noop$
  }
}

...

Cycle.run(main, {
  DOM: makeDOMDriver('#app'),

  // non-operative driver
  noop: noop$ => { noop$.addListener(
    {next: noop => {}, error: ()=>{}, complete: ()=>{}}
  ) }
})
```

[Codepen.io Run Setup example](https://codepen.io/bloodyKnuckles/pen/EEozag?editors=0011)

---

Another way is to run your setup script in a driver and trigger it with an `of` observable.

```
function main (sources) {

  // trigger observable
  const setup$ = xs.of(1)

...

  return {
    DOM: vdom$,
    setup: setup$
  }
}

Cycle.run(main, {
  DOM: makeDOMDriver('#app'),

  // setup driver
  setup: setup$ => { setup$.addListener({next: setup => {
    // setup code goes here
    console.log('run setup: ', document.querySelector('#app').children.length)
  }, error: ()=>{}, complete: ()=>{}}) }
})
```

[Codepen.io Setup Driver example.](https://codepen.io/bloodyKnuckles/pen/VXyJJv?editors=0010)

---

If user input is needed before creating the DOM element:

```
function main (sources) {

  const click$ = sources.DOM.select('div#clickme').events('click')
  const vdom$ = click$
    .mapTo(div('#newDomElement',"I'm new."))
    .startWith(div('#clickme','Click me.'))

  return {
    DOM: vdom$,
    setup: click$
  }
}

Cycle.run(main, {
  DOM: makeDOMDriver('#app'),
  setup: setup$ => { setup$.addListener({next: setup => {
    // setup code goes here
    initAutoComplDummy()
  }, error: ()=>{}, complete: ()=>{}}) }
})
```

[Codepen.io Setup Driver After User Input example](https://codepen.io/bloodyKnuckles/pen/PRQVrv?editors=0010)

Answer (score 1):

I actually asked my question incorrectly, because when I implemented my solution, I realized the autocomplete was not on the first page, so bloodyKnuckles solution, while correctly answering the question, did not fix my issue.

So here is how to run javascript after an arbitrary item has been rendered on the DOM in cycle.js

inside of your main

```
 const elementId$ = sources.DOM.elements().filter(c => (document.getElementById('myRenderedElementId') !== null)).filter(c => c).take(1).map(c => {
       // run custom javascript
    });

    elementId$.addListener({
        next: function (value) {
        },
        error: function (err) {
            alert('err: ' + name + ' ' + err);
        },
        complete: function () {
        }
    });
```

Comment: I'd like to learn more, so some questions. Did you get an error when using either of the examples I gave? Are you accessing rendered elements? If so how? Please add an example of the custom javascript you are running. I updated my codepen.io examples to show that they are accessing a rendered element. And I made a [codepen with your answer](https://codepen.io/bloodyKnuckles/pen/BrYzzo?editors=0011). Thanks for the select and upvote!!

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles I have a simple code pen here to illustrate that the target element is not rendered until after a click.  https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gevZLg?editors=0011

Comment: Do you require user input before creating the DOM element? Or can you create the DOM element on page load.

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles User input, because I am asking for permission to access geolocation

Comment: How about this: [Run Setup Driver After User Input](https://codepen.io/bloodyKnuckles/pen/PRQVrv?editors=0010).
(I added this approach to my answer.)

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles that looks like a good approach, interesting that the order of the return matters, this for example doesn't work, https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BrYbGz?editors=0010

Comment: You can add a short `delay` to solve that problem: `setup: click$.compose(delay(100))` [Codepen.io w/Delay](https://codepen.io/bloodyKnuckles/pen/mxxVbe?editors=0010)